# Python | Requests and Selenium throwing Timeout Errors on a random basis

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I have python scripts for 20 websites which check whether a website is up or down.
These scripts run every 30 minutes daily.

6 websites are checked through `selenium` Firefox and `selenium` Chrome. (12 python scripts, 2 for each) [headless mode]

7 websites are checked through `requests` module (404 check). (7 python scripts)

7 websites are checked through `selenium` Firefox. (7 python scripts) [headless mode]

The scripts run as expected, but on a random day at a random time, any one script will throw a `Timeout Exception` error or `Read Timeout Exception` error.

I can provide more information if necessary.

**Edit:**

Python Codes

1. Firefox Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import sys
from datetime import datetime as dt

browser = None

def login(concatenated):
    try:
        Split_V = concatenated.split(';')
        App_URL = str(Split_V[0])
        Logo_ID = str(Split_V[1])
        Output = ''

        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'

        desired_caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
        desired_caps = desired_caps.update(
            {'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'acceptSslCerts': True})

        global browser

        browser = webdriver.Firefox(
            executable_path=r'F:\geckodriver.exe', options=options, capabilities=desired_caps)
        browser.set_page_load_timeout(25)
        browser.get(App_URL)
        logo_exists = WebDriverWait(browser, 25).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Logo_ID)))

        if(logo_exists):
            Output = True
        else:
            Output = False

        return Output

    except:
        today = dt.now()
        ErrorMessage = today.strftime(
            "%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S") + ' - Error occurred : ' + App_URL + ' ' + str(sys.exc_info())
        with open(r"F:\ErrorLog.txt", "a") as a_file:
            a_file.write("\n")
            a_file.write(ErrorMessage)
        browser.save_screenshot("Screenshot.png")

        return False

    finally:
        browser.quit()
```

2. Chrome Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt

browser = None

def login(concatenated):
    try:
        Split_V = concatenated.split(';')
        App_URL = str(Split_V[0])
        Logo_ID = str(Split_V[1])
        Output = ' '

        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
        options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

        desired_caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        desired_caps = desired_caps.update({'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'acceptSslCerts': True})

        global browser
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'F:\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', options=options, desired_capabilities=desired_caps)
        browser.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        browser.get(App_URL)

        logo_exists = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Logo_ID)))

        if(logo_exists):
            Output = True
        else:
            Output = False

        return Output

    except:
        today = dt.now()
        ErrorMessage = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S") + ' - Error occurred : ' + App_URL + ' ' + str(sys.exc_info())
        with open(r"F:\ErrorLog.txt", "a") as a_file:
            a_file.write("\n")
            a_file.write(ErrorMessage)
    
        return False

    finally:
        browser.quit()
```

3. Requests Code

```
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
from datetime import datetime as dt
import sys

def CheckUrl(AppUrl):
    try:
        r = requests.get(AppUrl,timeout=10,verify = False)
        status = ""
        if r.status_code != 404:
            status = "UP"
        else: 
            status = "DOWN"
        return status
    
    except:
        today = dt.now()
        ErrorMessage = today.strftime(
            "%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S") + ' - Error occurred : ' + AppUrl + ' ' + str(sys.exc_info())
            
        with open(r"F:\ErrorLog.txt", "a") as a_file:
            a_file.write("\n")
            a_file.write(ErrorMessage)
        
        return False
```

Error Log

Following are the errors captured through my Exception Handling code for a few applications

```
January 02, 2022 05:01:14 - Error occurred : Website F (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.858\n  (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.110)', None, None), <traceback object at 0x000001FCD51C16C0>)
January 03, 2022 11:03:43 - Error occurred : Website A (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('', None, None), <traceback object at 0x00000218B880CB00>)
January 03, 2022 11:03:57 - Error occurred : Website A (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('', None, None), <traceback object at 0x000001DF61B0D440>)
January 03, 2022 16:31:43 - Error occurred : Website B (<class 'requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout'>, ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='Removed', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=20)")), <traceback object at 0x00000201C04083C0>)
January 04, 2022 02:30:53 - Error occurred : Website C (<class 'requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout'>, ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='Removed', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)")), <traceback object at 0x0000028AEBC94E40>)
January 04, 2022 03:00:54 - Error occurred : Website C (<class 'requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout'>, ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='Removed', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)")), <traceback object at 0x0000018836B95DC0>)
January 04, 2022 08:30:55 - Error occurred : Website C (<class 'requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout'>, ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='Removed', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)")), <traceback object at 0x000002A45F3F4F40>)
January 04, 2022 11:30:32 - Error occurred : Wesbite D (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>, WebDriverException('Access is denied. (os error 5)', None, None), <traceback object at 0x00000198CE9FD600>)
January 04, 2022 19:03:02 - Error occurred : Website E (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('TimedPromise timed out after 10000 ms', None, None), <traceback object at 0x00000251662A2C00>)
January 04, 2022 22:00:56 - Error occurred : Website D (<class 'requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout'>, ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='Removed', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=20)")), <traceback object at 0x00000231AEFD0480>)
January 05, 2022 00:31:26 - Error occurred : Website F (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('TimedPromise timed out after 25000 ms', None, None), <traceback object at 0x0000021925067F40>)
January 05, 2022 20:01:32 - Error occurred : Website F (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('TimedPromise timed out after 25000 ms', None, None), <traceback object at 0x000001A890E77FC0>)
January 05, 2022 20:31:29 - Error occurred : Website F (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('TimedPromise timed out after 25000 ms', None, None), <traceback object at 0x000001F7B9465180>)
January 06, 2022 13:01:21 - Error occurred : Website F (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 9.858\n  (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.110)', None, None), <traceback object at 0x000001D503B35940>)
January 06, 2022 17:34:28 - Error occurred : Website G (<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>, TimeoutException('', None, None), <traceback object at 0x000001AF8D8E8B80>)
January 07, 2022 05:31:49 - Error occurred : Website B (<class 'requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout'>, ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='outlook.office365.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=20)")), <traceback object at 0x0000022CF8F70B80>)
```

Website C is checked through requests module.

Rest of the websites are checked through Firefox or Chrome (if mentioned in the error).

Note: I have removed the hostname from the Errors.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the error stacktrace.

Comment: have you tried increasing the timeout for your various waits?

Comment: @BreaksSoftware Yes, I have. 20 seconds, 25 seconds and the rest of them are still 10 seconds. You will also be able to see that in the error log.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I will be providing the code soon.